# Path between two points

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017

I have a table with connections between two points:

[image]

```
RidgeId PointId1    PointId2
1   1   2
2   3   2
3   17  10
4   18  10
6   18  11
7   11  3
8   4   1
9   13  4
10  16  13
11  15  16
12  5   15
13  19  5
14  20  19
15  21  20
16  8   21
17  12  8
18  6   12
```

I would like to find path between two points.
f. egz.

from 3 to 10

- 3, 11
- 11, 18
- 18, 10

How to write a query to get this result?

EDit:

How to add information about consistent connection with original row like this:

[image]

Comment: *Consumable* sample data as *text* not an image, would be immensely helpful, along with any attempt yo have already made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a recursive CTE for this. Since you could have multiple routes, the easiest way to return a resultset is to return it as JSON

- There are two anchors and two recursions because we can go from Point1 to Point2 or v.v. for each node

```sql
DECLARE @start int = 3;
DECLARE @end int = 10;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
      Point2 = p.PointId2,
      p.RidgeId,
      Json = (
          SELECT p.RidgeId, p.PointId1, p.PointId2
          FOR JSON PATH
      )
    FROM Points p
    WHERE p.PointId1 = @start
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      Point2 = p.PointId1,
      p.RidgeId,
      Json = (
          SELECT p.RidgeId, p.PointId1, p.PointId2
          FOR JSON PATH
      )
    FROM Points p
    WHERE p.PointId2 = @start
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      Point2 = p.PointId2,
      p.RidgeId,
      Json = JSON_MODIFY(cte.Json, 'append $', JSON_QUERY((
          SELECT p.RidgeId, p.PointId1, p.PointId2
          FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )))
    FROM Points p
    JOIN cte ON cte.Point2 = p.PointId1
    WHERE p.RidgeId <> cte.RidgeId

    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
      Point2 = p.PointId1,
      p.RidgeId,
      Json = JSON_MODIFY(cte.Json, 'append $', JSON_QUERY((
          SELECT p.RidgeId, p.PointId1, p.PointId2
          FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
      )))
    FROM Points p
    JOIN cte ON cte.Point2 = p.PointId2
    WHERE p.RidgeId <> cte.RidgeId
)

SELECT Json
FROM cte
WHERE cte.Point2 = @end;
```

| Result |
| --- |
| [{"RidgeId":7,"PointId1":11,"PointId2":3}, {"RidgeId":6,"PointId1":18,"PointId2":11}, {"RidgeId":4,"PointId1":18,"PointId2":10}] |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=61971b1bf55f5d747008fb18f7783d28)

This does not deal well with a loop in the nodes. Ideally you should check for no loops by breaking out the JSON in each recursive section and checking we are not going back on ourselves

Comment: Thank you. If there is limitation of 100 recursion?

Comment: Then you add on `OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)` however I would not do that unless yuo knew you needed it, it is more likely you have an infinite loop somewhere

Comment: This is the mountain ridge. This is imposible to have the infinite loop. Thanks.

Comment: So you do or you don't have an infinite loop?

Comment: I don't have an infinite loop.

Comment: Could you write me how to convert this solution to slq table and add new column with information if connection is consistent direction with original row? 
RidgeId PointId1 PointId2 Revert
7 11 3 0
6 18 11 0
4 18 10 1

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You may want to create a new question for that

Comment: How to convert this [{"RidgeId":7,"PointId1":11,"PointId2":3},{"RidgeId":6,"PointId1":18,"PointId2":11},{"RidgeId":4,"PointId1":18,"PointId2":10}] to sql table?

Comment: You can use `OPENJSON` for that. I suggest you create a new question